# SQL update values randomly to wipe data / make it unreadable

Tags: sql, random, sql-server-2014

Here is the situation, 
I have a table with some data that are used in Production.
When i do a backup that is available for every developer,
i want to change the current sensitive data to random values so that :

- i don't wipe it completely so i still have data
- the data are still usable (not the same value for the complete column, respect of Foreign keys, etc...)

For the moment i imagined something like this for the nvarchar fields  :

```
update Client set Name = SUBSTRING (CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', Name), 2),10,30)
```

i saw some posts like this :

1. [SQl Update from table of random Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560392/sql-update-from-table-of-random-names)
2. [SQL Update row column with random lookup value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141181/sql-update-row-column-with-random-lookup-value)

but it seems to use big queries that i'd prefer to avoid.
Isn't there a better approach to randomize a complete table without scripting specific script for each table/column ? (btw i'm using SQL Server 2014)
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes, it is called dynamic sql. First you read metadata, then you build query and execute it.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23786/data-obfuscation-in-sql-server